# Proposed tag synonym: "get-be" as a synonym of "get-passive"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

All of the questions with the [get-be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/get-be) tag seem to be about the "get-passive" construction. For example, the top-voted question in the "get-be" tag, [Why is “to get” sometimes used where “to be” could be used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-to-get-sometimes-used-where-to-be-could-be-used), asks about "got uploaded", "got thrown", "got caught" vs "was uploaded", "was thrown", "was caught". So I think it would make sense to make [get-be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/get-be) a synonym of [get-passive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/get-passive).

I find "get-passive" preferable as the target because it seems slightly broader, but the possible slight difference in meaning does not seem enough to warrant the existence of separate tags. But maybe "get-be" could be better as a target because then the tag would cover a few types of similar constructions where "get" is used with something other than a past participle. What do people think?

Comment: I have a question: can you give me an example of get-be versus get-passive.  I think I get get-passive (get lost?) but not: get-be.

Comment: @Lambie: the "get-be" tag seems to be used for questions about the use of *get* vs. *be.* For example, the top-voted question in the "get-be" tag, [Why is “to get” sometimes used where “to be” could be used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-to-get-sometimes-used-where-to-be-could-be-used),  asks about "got uploaded", "got thrown", "got caught"  vs "was uploaded", "was thrown", "was caught".

Comment: Ah right, gotcha. Using get instead of be. I think get-passive would be better. So, I agree with you.

Comment: @sumelic Can you put these examples in the question? That would clarify it a lot.

Comment: I only saw one question where [tag:get-passive] would be inappropriate, but [tag:get-be] didn't make sense on that question in the first place, so I've retagged it.  I'm in favor of the [tag:get-passive] target.  It's true that [tag:get-be] could cover some cases [tag:get-passive] wouldn't, but that seems to be a purely hypothetical problem at the moment.

Comment: I would never think to tag something as `get-be` if I had a question about this construction. `get-passive` seems better, but they're both pretty confusing